# Memcached chunk limit

Tags: membership

Why is there a hardcoded chunk limit (.5 meg after compression) in [memcached](http://memcached.org/)? Has anyone recompiled theirs to up it? I know I should not be sending big chunks like that around, but these extra heavy chunks happen for me from time to time and wreak havoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question used to be in the [official FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ)

[What are some limits in memcached I might hit? (Wayback Machine)](http://web.archive.org/web/20080927061146/http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ)

To quote:

> The simple limits you will probably see with memcache are the key and 
>   item size limits. Keys are restricted to 250 characters. Stored data 
>   cannot exceed 1 megabyte in size, since that is the largest typical 
>   slab size."

The FAQ has now been revised and there are now two separate questions covering this:

[What is the maxiumum key length? (250 bytes)](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_maxiumum_key_length?_%28250_bytes%29)

> The maximum size of a key is 250 characters. Note this value will be
>   less if you are using client "prefixes" or similar features, since the
>   prefix is tacked onto the front of the original key. Shorter keys are
>   generally better since they save memory and use less bandwidth.

[Why are items limited to 1 megabyte in size?](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_items_limited_to_1_megabyte_in_size?)

> Ahh, this is a popular question!
>
> Short answer: Because of how the memory allocator's algorithm works.
>
> Long answer: Memcached's memory storage engine (which will be
>   pluggable/adjusted in the future...), uses a slabs approach to memory
>   management. Memory is broken up into slabs chunks of varying sizes,
>   starting at a minimum number and ascending by a factorial up to the
>   largest possible value.
>
> Say the minimum value is 400 bytes, and the maximum value is 1
>   megabyte, and the factorial is 1.20:
>
> slab 1 - 400 bytes slab 2 - 480 bytes slab 3 - 576 bytes ... etc.
>
> The larger the slab, the more of a gap there is between it and the
>   previous slab. So the larger the maximum value the less efficient the
>   memory storage is. Memcached also has to pre-allocate some memory for
>   every slab that exists, so setting a smaller factorial with a larger
>   max value will require even more overhead.
>
> There're other reason why you wouldn't want to do that... If we're
>   talking about a web page and you're attempting to store/load values
>   that large, you're probably doing something wrong. At that size it'll
>   take a noticeable amount of time to load and unpack the data structure
>   into memory, and your site will likely not perform very well.
>
> If you really do want to store items larger than 1MB, you can
>   recompile memcached with an edited `slabs.c:POWER_BLOCK` value, or use
>   the inefficient malloc/free backend. Other suggestions include a
>   database, MogileFS, etc.