# memcache php store than 1MB

Tags: php

my memcached server is configured to store 512MB but if i try use php class memcache() to store data from file get content (file size 20MB) memcache dosent store.

```
$cache2 = new \Memcache;
$cache2->connect('localhost', 11211) or die('Could not connect to memcache serwer');
$sql = $cache2->get('sql');
if(!$sql){

        $content = file_get_contents('system/repository/sql/polska_lokalizacje.sql');
        $cache2->set('sql', $content, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 20);
        $sql = $cache2->get('sql');

}
echo $sql;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349/memcached-chunk-limit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125806/how-do-you-work-around-memcacheds-key-value-limitations might give you some insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://web.archive.org/web/20080927061146/http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ

> Stored data cannot exceed 1 megabyte in size, since that is the
>   largest typical slab size.

Comment: so if i want store 20MB in memcached in the same key i have to split my content file to 20 parts (every part mount 1MB) And than use loop to store in same key??

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't seem to be a good idea to store a 20m "thing" in memcached... It is planned to be used with lots of small items.